# Homework: questions about probability distribution functions and probability density function

Tags: statistics

The book I'm having is not good in explaining, and since it is not written in English I have a hard time looking up what is meant. I noticed there's a lot of terminology that seems quite vague.

The questions that I have to answer concerns the following function:

F(x) = { $0$ for $x < 0$, $\frac{x}{4}$ for $0 \lt x \lt 4$, 1 for x $\gt$ 4 }

Q: Verify that the function meets the requirements for a probability distribution function

So here's what I think I know; F(x) is the area of f(x), but it is not shown as an actual area like in a picture of the graph of f(x) with some area underneath it, it is actually a line, like f(x). So I scoured the book for requirements, didn't find any. I asked questions to the author of the book, and the answer was that I had to look at the requirements of a probability model, which were

1. P(A) $\geq 0$
2. P(A $\cup$ B) = P(A) + P(B), if A $\cap$ B = $\emptyset$
3. P(U) = 1

Which I don't know how to apply this to my problem, actually.

Some searching on the internet, especially these video's [Finding Probabilities and Percentiles for a Continuous Probability Distribution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPm7FdajBvc&index=2&list=PLvxOuBpazmsPDZGwqhhjE3KkLWnTD34R0) and [Deriving the Mean and Variance of a Continuous Probability Distribution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ro7dayHU5DQ&index=3&list=PLvxOuBpazmsPDZGwqhhjE3KkLWnTD34R0) suggest that the requirements are that x $\geq 0$ for all x, and that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = 1$. Okay, so I'm one step closer, except that I don't have f(x).

Also, there's another problem; if I look at F(x), and think of it as a graph, how on earth can it ever be 1? The line of F(x) is 1 from $x \gt 4$ to $\infty$ alone, then there's the bit of the line that goes from 0 to 1. Surely, that must be more than 1?

That leads me to the second question:

b. What is the probability density function?

The probability density function I think is f(x). It is the function that gives the bell curve of a normal distribution. I do not know how to take the integral of this piecewise function. So searching suggest I take the derivative of $\frac{x}{4}$. Is this correct, and if so, why?

Comment: Try $f(x)=F'(x)$ for every $x$ such that $F'(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$, a function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is said to be a random variable if for every $x$, 
$$X^{-1}(-\infty,x]=\{\omega\in\Omega : X(\omega)\leqslant x\}\in\mathcal F. $$
The distribution function of $X$ is defined by $$F(x) = (\mathbb P\circ X^{-1})(-\infty,x] = \mathbb P(\omega\in\Omega : X(\omega)\leqslant x),$$
written as
$$ F(x) = \mathbb P(X\leqslant x)$$
for short. To verify that the given function is indeed a probability distribution function, you need to show that

- $F$ is monotone increasing, i.e. $x<y$ implies $F(x)\leqslant F(y)$.
- $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1$
- $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0$
- $F$ is right-continuous, i.e. $\lim_{t\downarrow x}F(t)=F(x)$ for all $x$.

The three properties are clear if you plot the function. It turns out here that $F$ is continuous (even though it is piecewise-defined), and that a continuous distribution function is differentiable almost everywhere. So if we take the derivative, we have

$$
f(x) := F'(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0,& x < 0\\
\frac14,& 0<x<4\\
0,& x> 4
\end{cases}
$$
This function $f$ is a probability density function. We can verify this by observing that $f$ is nonnegative, and 
$$\int_\mathbb R f(x)\mathsf dx = \int_0^4 \frac14\mathsf dx = 1.$$

Comment: You're welcome!